# Power Bank does't able supply power when connected to buck boost converter and Modem?

Tags: power-supply

I've a modem which has GPRS and GPS Module interfaced with PIC24F micro controller. The modem input voltage range is 8-35v and 300mA.We have planned to fix that modem to car battery, so we designed that modem with input voltage range 8-35v. But now we changed our mind not to connect with car battery. We would like to connect that modem to a power bank. We bought a 4charge power bank[@ link](http://goo.gl/YaCqeH)! . The power bank has two output usb port with 5v 1A and 5v 2A respectively. Since our modem input voltage range is 8-35v so we decided to put a step-up the voltage by booster(XL6009 DC-DC step up module) to boost up 5v to 12v.When we switch on the power bank ,the modem doesn't getting any supply but sometimes Modem is working (getting supply). What could be the problem in this scenario and suggest any idea to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Your power bank, boost converter or modem could be broken.

Comment: if i connect the booster to some other controller board it's working and Modem also working when connected Fixed power supply @12v ...@ plasmaHH

Comment: These power banks sometimes have a minimum load when connected or they won't work. They shut off the output if the draw is too low when they check. A power switch on the USB VCC line may help.

Comment: @Passerby: what really would help would be measurements and specifications...

Comment: what would be the difference when connected to switch and connected directly to power bank?  Sufficiently our Modem will draw up to 300mA in idle and 800mA when sending data to server.@ PlasmaHH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your power bank 99% likely already has a DC-DC SMPS converter inside. The internal converter is used to convert between ~4.2-5.5V USB power *input* down to current charge level of the contained (usually LiPO or LiIon) battery(s), then back up to 5v for its usb *output*.

Nearly all power banks use some form of control circuitry that's designed around the >=500mA current drawn by 'normal' usb-charged (not usb-run) devices. As pointed out by @Passerby, you're likely triggering a 'powersave timeout' on this circuit feature while your modem is either not running, or only drawing ~300mA for too long.

Most likely, your best solution would be to keep the original powerbank converter, but only use it for charging; then attach your step-up (boost) output converter directly to the batteries inside the powerpack, and use a switch to enable/disable your converter (every converter stabe you use has efficiency losses, so 1 is nearly always better than 2 in series, anywise). Ideally, you could use the same switch to ena le/disable the boost convsrter *and* the modem, thus improving eass-of-use & end-user transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the DC/DC booster to one based on th LM2577 chip. XL6009 operates from 5 V input, LM2577 - from 3,5 V. Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: The operating voltage of the boost converter is not the issue here. It's not like the powerbank will ever give anything that isn't 5V